# How to avoid too many stream names created in KVS Kinesis Video Stream when trying to ingest data from AWS connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-connect

Am trying to ingest data from AWS connect to AWS KVS (Kinesis Video Stream) but for  one call conversation over AWS connect too many KVS records creating, please suggest solution to avoid same and get single entry in KVS for a call.

PFA screenshots of my KVS .[image]

---------> Here entries created for single call on aws connect.

PFA my AWS connect flow design ------------> [image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing set working queue block and Transfer Queue block after media streaming block. Hope that will help